# rails: pass variable to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I pass a variable to a partial using this code? :

```
<%= render @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order("created_at DESC") %>
```

I want to pass "id=1" and then in _improvement_action, use that variable like:

```
<%= id %>
```

EDIT:

This is my improvement_action partial:

https://gist.github.com/luisamaro0/6597084f2de1dc33cde7c014ea9f23a5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3, passing local variable to partial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279651/rails-3-passing-local-variable-to-partial)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a local variable like so:

`render "a_partial", :a_local_variable => whatever, :another_variable => another`

See this question for more details: [Rails 3, passing local variable to partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279651/rails-3-passing-local-variable-to-partial)

Comment: i cant pass a created local variable ?

Comment: Yes, you can, my mistake for misunderstanding your question. I've updated my answer and linked you to a similar question.

Comment: I saw that question before and tried like that: `<%= render @performance_indicator.improvement_actions, :a_local_variable => 'whatever'  %>` but dont work, when calling the variable in the partial

Comment: It works for me, are attempting to access the local variable as a symbol? (You shouldn't be)

Comment: im trying to access like this: `<%= a_local_variable %>`

Comment: If you try <%= local_variable.nil? %> what shows up in your page?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `local_variable' for #<#

Comment: The code I posted was an example, when copying and pasting you need to replace "local_variable" with the name of your real local variable.

Comment: i rendered like this: `<%= render @performance_indicator.improvement_actions, :local_variable => '1'  %>` and called the variable like this: `<%= local_variable %>`

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a variable like this

```
<%= render partial: 'partial_name', locals: {id: '1'} %>
```

Comment: i tried like this but it doesnt work `<%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', locals: {id: '1'}, collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions %>`

Comment: undefined local variable or method `id'

Comment: can you post `improvement_action` partial??

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax out:

```
<%= render @performance_indicator.improvement_actions, locals: { local_variable: 1 %>
# then <%= local_variable %>
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `local_variable'