# How can I yield a "future" content_for tag in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, partial, yield, content-for

I have a template with 2 partials. In the first one, I am yieleding content which is only defined in the second partial (with a content_for tag). The problem is that the yield does not recognize that content yet since it was not defined.

If I reverse the order of the partials the yield recognized the content, yet the layout is not as I desire obviously...

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Is this something more than having the first partial pass `:locals` when it invokes the other?  See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402556/rails-confused-about-syntax-for-passing-locals-to-partials -- the accepted answer has a great summary.

Comment: didn't find any answer to this in the link, and also couldn't figure out what you suggested :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was actually an easy fix.
I moved the second partial into a content_for block placed above the first partial, and then just yielded it instead of declaring it as a partial.