# Render @object and locals vs render :partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial, partials

I want to pass a local variable that contains the origin to come on a specific page, this variable contains just a symbol with the value.

When I use this code it works perfect, the origin variable is accessible in the partial :

```
render :partial => "products", :collection => @products, :locals => {:origin => :gallery}
```

But when I use this code, the origin is not set and not accessible in the partial :

```
render @products, :locals => {:origin => :gallery}
```

What is the difference here? Is the second line of code not render the partial like the first line?

Comment: Should it not be `:locals => {:origin => :gallery}`?

Comment: @Nick indeed this was a typo, in my application I use the :locals => {:origin => :gallery}, so that was not the problem. But good catch!:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<%= render @products %>
```

Is indeed the shorthand syntax for rendering a partial. But with the shorthand syntax, Rails will ignore the ":locals" variable. There's more on this in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).

So if you want to pass extra options to the render, you have to specify ":partial => ...". If you want to know why this happens, you can take a look at the Rails [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d3d9a150a4ba1084cf28fd26be2a154f4540952/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb#L18).

Comment: you can pass a local variable to the end of `@products` it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation here: [Rails: confused about syntax for passing locals to partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402556/rails-confused-about-syntax-for-passing-locals-to-partials#)

The short version is that you can just omit `:locals` in the second example:

```
render @products, :origin => :gallery
```

Comment: Definitely doesn't work for me (Rails 3.2.13). The link to the other question is helpful. But I think your example is wrong because you're trying to use the collection shortcut, which unfortunately doesn't let you pass locals. You're probably thinking of `render "product", :origin => :gallery`