# Local variable is accessible through the debugger, but ERB complains that no such variable is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I'm doing the following:

```
<%= render :partial => "folder/content", :locals => {:var1 => featured_content, :featured => true} %>
```

Inside the _content.html.erb partial, I can access the first local variable fine. var1 works great. However, the second local variable is having problems.

I put a call to the debugger right before the line I want to use the featured variable. I can access that variable (and its value) just fine. In fact, in the debugger, I can list all the local variables ... and I see that "featured" is one of them.

But when I run my server, I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `featured' for #<#<Class:0x002g9ff8617940>:0x007f9aa251eb38>
```

What could possibly be happening here? It makes no sense to me at all!

**UPDATE:**

If I do the following:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :featured %>
  <% 'hello world' if featured %>
<% end %>
```

then everything works perfectly fine. However, if featured is not within the scope of the if statement, then I get an error.

This is total madness as far as I can see -- I would love some insight into what is happening and why its happening only to this one poor variable (the other variable is completely fine mind you...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the has_key is the only option that works right now (please see my edit). I am going to close this since I haven't gotten any better responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<%= render "folder/content", :var1 => featured_content, :featured => true %>
```

Look at this for more info:

[Rails: confused about syntax for passing locals to partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402556/rails-confused-about-syntax-for-passing-locals-to-partials)

Comment: Tried that already actually, and no luck. I found one other question where someone had the same issue I was having. he restarted his IDE and server and everything magically worked. Not the case for me.