# pass variable to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, zurb-foundation

I am trying to pass a variable to a partial so that it can be called within the partial
This is how i am rendering the partial

```
 = render :partial => "layouts/reveal_delete", :resource => @schedule
```

and this is how i am calling the variable within the partial, though it doesnt appear to be working

```
#RevealDelete.reveal-modal
%a.close-reveal-modal ×
  %h3= "Delete #{@resource}"
  %p Are you sure you want to delete this?
  =link_to "Delete #{@resource}", @resource, :method => :delete, :class => "button close-reveal-modal"
  %a.button.alert.close-reveal-modal Cancel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it this way:

```
= render :partial => "layouts/reveal_delete", :locals => { :resource => @schedule }
```

And then within the partial, you can use it by referring to `resource` (no `@`), like this:

```
%h3= "Delete #{resource}"
```

Typically, though, you would name your local variable `schedule` to match the instance variable, so:

```
= render :partial => "layouts/reveal_delete", :locals => { :schedule => @schedule }
```

And then you can refer to `schedule` in your partial.

Also if you want, you can drop the `:partial` and `:locals` option keys, and use this shorter syntax:

```
= render "layouts/reveal_delete", :schedule => @schedule
```

Here, Rails assumes that if you pass in a string as your first argument, then the first argument is your partial name and the remainder is interpreted as local variable assignments. Here's [an answer discussing this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402556/rails-confused-about-syntax-for-passing-locals-to-partials):

Also more info in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).

Comment: perfect, though i was told :locals was depreciated in rails 3

Comment: I see it in the docs, so it should still be ok to use. But you can also drop the `:partial =>` key and `:locals =>`, which makes it shorter: `= render "layouts/reveal_delete", :schedule => @schedule`.

Comment: how would i use a link_to similar to this `%li= link_to "javascript:void(0);", :data => {"reveal-id" => "RevealDelete"}, :item => full_name(user), :resource => user` and have the variables passed to the partial. as i only want to render the partial once and be able to exchange variables

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: say i had multiple users within a table, and option to delete them, id only want to render the partial for deleting once, and then pass their variables through