# Rails 4: passing multiple arguments to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm able to pass a single argument from a view to a partial, but for some reason when I add a second it is undefined (nil class).

Here's how I call the partial in the view:

```
<%= render 'project_form', locals: {project: @project, form_method: 'patch'} %>
```

Here's the top of the partial (_project_form.html.erb):

```
<%= logger.debug( @form_method ) %>
```

This prints "true" in the view, and logs nothing (a blank line) in the log.

Why isn't it receiving the second argument? I can debug @project and it's the class I expect.

**Update:**
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402556/rails-confused-about-syntax-for-passing-locals-to-partials), you need to modify the render syntax slightly to pass multiple arguments.

So I had two problems: 1) the variable scope, 2) the `render :partial` syntax needs to be explicit to pass more than one local variable.

Comment: if @project is working then it probably means you dont even need to pass it (since it's an instance variable and already available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a local variable you are trying to print. Try this in your partial instead of `@form_method`:

```
<%= logger.debug( form_method ) %>
```

and I think the below will print value in your partial :

```
<%= form_method %>
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. Can you help me understand why @project was defined? Does the scope of the instance variable apply automatically into the partial?

Comment: Yes, the @project scope will automatically applied into all the partials, that you will render into your view.