# Rendering Partial Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whats is the difference between

```
render partial: 'shared/errors', locals: { errors: @project.errors }
```

and

```
render 'shared/errors', errors: @project.errors
```

when rendering a partial `shared/_errors.rb`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402556/rails-confused-about-syntax-for-passing-locals-to-partials?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both seem to be doing exact same thing, but in some cases you have to explicitly specify render partial: '...' if you want to use certain options such as :layout, :collection etc.

As stated here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials